# key weights/Variable not found in checkpoint tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Trying to load my trained tensorflow model, but it is coming up with this erro message:

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key weights/Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2_1/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1/shape_and_slices)]]

Any ideas on what could have happened to the weights, or how I can restore them? Or am I just restoring the model wrong?

Below is the relevant code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
            if i % 100 == 0:
                train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
                    x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
                print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
                saver.save(sess,"/Users/prakash/Desktop/hackathon/Trained_Data/modelstep.ckpt",global_step=i)
                print "saved ",i

        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

    saver.save(sess,"/Users/prakash/Desktop/hackathon/Trained_Data/model.ckpt")
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

And here is how I am trying to restore:

```
saver.restore(sess,"Trained_Data/modelstep.ckpt")
```

Comment: I believe modelstep.ckpt and model.ckpt are the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Key <variable\_name> not found in checkpoint Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179556/key-variable-name-not-found-in-checkpoint-tensorflow)